# How to wrap the text 5 characters before the end of window?

Tags: vim, eol

I would like to wrap the text 5 characters before the end of window (without breaking the line).

I don't know how to do this without putting an EOL character in the text (wrapmargin/textwidth).

Answer (score 4):

You need to set 3 options as follows:

```
:set linebreak
:set wrap
:set nolist
```

If any of these are set otherwise (e.g. `:set list`), then it won't work.

Additionally, there is an option to set a character which will display at the beginning of wrapped lines. e.g.:

```
:set showbreak=>
```

If you want to turn that feature off again, set it to an empty string:

```
:set showbreak=
```

Note that even though wrapped lines *look* like lines in their own right, Vim still considers them to be a single line. So moving the cursor down with the `j` key will move it on to the next numbered line, rather than the next displayed line. This makes better sense if you have line numbers displayed (`:set number`). If you want to move up and down through display lines, you can use `gk` and `gj` instead. Here are a few more *g* commands that you will find useful:

```
Numbered line           Display line
-------------           ------------
j                       gj
k                       gk
$                       g$
0                       g0
^                       g^
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `linebreak` is the setting you're looking for?

```
:se linebreak
```

Comment: That paired with the `'wrap'` option will perform visual wrapping of lines at word boundaries.  There isn't a way to specify exactly how far from the edge of the window the wrapping will occur.

Comment: @jamessan: That is absolutely correct. But it looks to me like the OP is trying get a better visual overview of wrapping text, where I though that this option might help.